# Measuring mash temperature

Tags: mash, temperature

For mashing, I have kettle and steel grain basket. Heat is provided via a gas stove. I heat the water to a few degrees above mash-in temperature and then ease in the grain basket.

When I measure temperature of my mash I find there is temperature variance between the bottom, middle and the top of the grain basket. It varies by a good five to six degrees between the top and bottom of the basket

Now, if I have to measure the temperature of the mash while attempting to do a step mash, from where should I be measuring the temperature (bottom, middle, top) ?
Or do I stir the mash until it is consistent through out and only then consider measuring the temperature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a combination of averaging, stirring and recirculating.  My mashtun has a large open area under the false bottom.  I drain some hot wort off the bottom and add it to the top of the grain bed - - -> then stir- - - > then average.

If you don't have a drain valve, you could raise and lower the grain basket a bit to even out the temperature, then stir.  5-6 degrees F variation isn't too bad as long the average is near the middle of the 145F to 158F mashing range.  Keep brewing, you'll sort out your methods!

5-6 C is quite a lot. You could remove 1/3 of the hot water from the kettle, then add the grain, then add the remaining hot water to the top of the grain basket. then stir. I do that in my mashtun to make the mixing easier. Seems to help.

Comment: Uhm when I say 5-6 degrees, I meant °C. I think that's a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Measure in 2 or 3 places, then take the average. Works well for me.